# Dynamic recordset populating textboxes

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, recordset

From a list of dates, I need to choose distinct dates, add 365 days, and then populate textboxes with each possible date.

I think I'm going to need to loop through a recordset and I've gotten this far but I'm not sure what the next step is.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim i As Long

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryListBox")

If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
Else
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1

            ' get list of dates
            ' if there is more than one date, populate subsequent boxes
            me.txtAnnv1.Value = DateAdd('d',365,[sdrdate])

        Next i
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

If I had:

```
+------+-----------+
| NAME |  SDRDATE  |
+------+-----------+
| Jane |  02/02/12 |
| Jane |  03/03/12 |
| Jane |  04/04/14 |
| Jane |  04/04/14 |
+------+-----------+
```

I would expect to see:

```
txtAnnv1 = 02/03/13
txtAnnv2 = 03/04/13
txtAnnv3 = 04/05/15
```

Comment: Why are you looping through the fields in the query results (`For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1`)? Isn't there only a single field containing the date?

Comment: Yes, there is only one field with the date. This is the first recordset loop I've written (or attempted) from scratch. So, that part is unneeded then?

Comment: Yes, it's unneeded. You simple need to loop through the recordset, which you are doing already. Do the textboxes already exist on your form, is your idea to add them dynamically?

Comment: I added the textboxes to the form but more of a placeholder/design. If they were always on the form, I'd try to hide them if NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following will get you pretty close. This is assuming that you textboxes already exist. It will first hide all of the textboxes that start with the name "txtAnnv" and clear their values. Then it will assign the values from the recordset to each textbox and unhide it as it goes.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim i As Long
Dim ctrl as Control


'Assuming that text boxes are already created and are named txtAnnv1, txtAnnv2, etc.. 
'Empty and hide all of the txtAnnv* text boxes
For each ctrl in me.Controls
    if left(ctrl.name,7) = "txtAnnv" then
        ctrl.visible = false
        ctrl.value = ""
    end if
Next ctrl

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryListBox")

If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
Else
    i = 1
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        'Set the value of each textbox to 1 year from the date in the recordset        
        me.controls("txtAnnv" & i).value = DateAdd('d', 365, rs.Fields(1).value)

        'unhide textbox
        me.controls("txtAnnv" & i).visible = true

        'iterate the counter that steps up to the next textbox
        i = i + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If


rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```